# Better notation for a product

Tags: notation

Let $A,B$ are two positive integers. Assuming that we have a product of the form 
$$
\prod_{\substack{a\mid A \\ \gcd(a,B)=1}}f(a).
$$
Is there a better notation to be used instead of $a\mid A$ and $\gcd(a,B)=1$ under the product sign
Bests

Comment: I would suggest two steps: first *define* the index set. Quite often that gives profit in the sequel too.

Comment: To flush out what @drhab means: Let $X=\left\{x: x|A \text{ and } \gcd(x,B)=1\right\}$. Then just take the product over all $x\in X$. And it's also pretty common to write $\gcd(x,B)=1$ as just $(x,B)=1$. Usually context implies we mean $\gcd$.

Comment: @drhab and BeaumonTaz, thanks for the comments. Indeed I am trying to avoid adding extra definition like a set $X$. But if this is the only possibility then I will do this.